# Changing value of an array with function call

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Suppose i have an array

```
int x[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

And a function

```
   int at(int p[],const int i){
   return p[i];
   }
```

and i'm trying to get access to the elements such as

```
cout << at(x,4);//works fine,output is 5  
cin >> at(x,3);// error
```

I know it's returning the constant of that index only, and we can't change the constants. So is there some way to somehow modify this function to get full access for the array's elements, to be able change the values on specified index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply change the function to return a reference instead. Change this:

```
int at(int p[],const int i){
```

To this:

```
int &at(int p[], const int i) {
```

> I know it's returning the constant of that index only, and we can't
>   change the constants.

That's not the problem. The issue is that if the function returns just an `int`, then you are returning an rvalue. [`cin >>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) however requires an lvalue, which is an object that is stored in an identifiable place in the memory. `x[3]` is such an `lvalue`, and by returning a reference to that, we are returning such an lvalue. By just returning an `int`, we would have only returned a copy of the value in `x[3]` and that copy wouldn't have an address, it is gone at the end of the statement.